# Removed WebMethod from ASP.NET Webservice, method still shows up

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I changed the signature of one of my web methods in a web service and couldn't get it to update, so now I've removed the whole method and rebuilt the project and that removed method still shows up and works!

Is there a WebService cache in Visual Studio I don't know about?

I've cleaned, rebuilt, built the project, even searching the project for that removed method retrieves no results so I presume this is a Visual Studio issue, not my code.

Screenshot of all the methods in visual studio next to the methods available when I run the service.  AddNewPerson is not in visual studio but IS in the service when I run it.: [http://imgur.com/seRXh.gif](https://imgur.com/seRXh.gif)

EDIT:
This isn't a web reference issue, this is the actual service, I haven't even got round to updating the reference on the other projects yet, I need to change this method first.

Comment: When  you F5 and run the web service, in the method listing

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your method shows up in your Web Reference which is a proxy class automatically generated by Visual Studio. In this case, right-click the Web Reference in Solution Explorer and choose **Update Web Reference**.

Comment: No, I'm working on the actual service - it's not referenced in another project yet.

Comment: @Gareth: then how do you track the old method's presence?

Comment: How do you mean track it?

I've made a web service, added some methods (see screenshot at the top) now removed one of them and when I run the web service it still shows up in the ASMX page you browse to when running it locally.

Comment: @Gareth: could you provide the source code (at least, stubs) to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

you should try to kill/stop the IIS process launched.
 
If you don't find the IIS icon in your bar, you can find it as a process named w3p.exe in your task manager and kill it.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  Killed all the processes and ended the service, re-ran it and it still shows up :(

Answer (score 0):

I think 7 years later you've probably fixed it already, but I was having the same problem in VS2015. The solution was to delete *.dll and *.pdb in the output folder and then build the project (not the whole solution)

Comment: '(not the whole solution)' Could you elaborate your solution a bit more? Then this answer may be more useful in the future.

Comment: Sure, in the solution explorer window you'll find a tree structure in which the root node's will say "Solution <your solution name> (n projects)". This is the solution node and will contain your projects and other files within the solution.
If you right-click the solution node, a pop up menu will appear and "Build solution" will be the first option. By selecting that option, all the projects within the solution will be rebuilt, and that's what I was saying you don't need to do.
Just find your project in the tree, right-click on that and select "Build".